# How to insert new page with contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i create element `page` with attribute `contenteditable="true"` and
but in last line i don't know how to create new page with event listener . help me give logic or help my code. thanks

this example my snippet code

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding 0;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

page {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<page contenteditable>
  <p>asd</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  how to after new line create new page ?
</page>
```

Comment: When you want to create the new page (related to which action?)

Comment: after end line page and create new same page in bottom first page, this like office word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `page` element in  a container `div`. Set height for the container `div`. Add `keydown` event handler to the `page` element. In the event handler, check if the height of the `page` element exceeds the height of the container `div`. If it does, append a new container `div` with a new `page` element to the `body` and set focus to the newly created `page` element.

Here is a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/s2TCksvgoun3a6tZ8MI9?p=preview.

This is just a basic working example. If you are trying to create a behavior similar to that of MS Word, you will have to improve upon this a lot.